# Plotly not showing last value of the series when using 'hv' line shape

Tags: python, plotly

I am working with a time series like this:

```
import pandas as pd
import plotly.graph_objects as go
from plotly.subplots import make_subplots

csv = [
    ['2019-05-01 00:00', 6],
    ['2019-05-01 00:30', 8],
    ['2019-05-01 01:00', 7],
    ['2019-05-01 01:30', 3],
    ['2019-05-01 02:00', 8],
    ['2019-05-01 02:30', 4]]

df = pd.DataFrame(csv, columns=["Timestamp", "Value"])
df["Timestamp"] = pd.to_datetime(df["Timestamp"])
df = df.set_index("Timestamp")
print(df)
```

So nothing special here, output:

```
                     Value
Timestamp                 
2019-05-01 00:00:00      6
2019-05-01 00:30:00      8
2019-05-01 01:00:00      7
2019-05-01 01:30:00      3
2019-05-01 02:00:00      8
2019-05-01 02:30:00      4
```

This is averaged data, meaning for example that the first value (6) is between 00:00 and 00:30.

I want to plot this data and also a bigger average, for example hourly average:

```
df_hourly = df.resample('1H').mean()
print(df_hourly)
```

Output:

```
                     Value
Timestamp                 
2019-05-01 00:00:00      7
2019-05-01 01:00:00      5
2019-05-01 02:00:00      6
```

Ok, so let's do it using Plotly's line shape 'hv':

```
fig = make_subplots(rows=2, shared_xaxes=True)

fig.add_trace(go.Scattergl(
    name='Value',
    x=df.index,
    y=df['Value'],
    line=dict(shape='hv'),
), row=1, col=1)

fig.add_trace(go.Scattergl(
    name='Hourly Value',
    x=df_hourly.index,
    y=df_hourly['Value'],
    line=dict(shape='hv'),
),row=2, col=1)
    
fig.show()
```

And here is the problem, this is the final plot:
[image: OutputPlotly]

I am interested in the line plot and my expectation is it will cover from the beginning of the data (0:00) to the end (just before 3:00). However the first ploted line ends at 2:30 and the second at 2:00.

I know all the data is being considered because all the markers are there. But visually talking, for me is very misleading that the lines corresponding to the last point are not being shown. If you use lines without markers, last point is not visible at all.

I understand this is the expected Plotly's behavior. So the question is, how can I fix it? Is there any easy way to plot a line from 0:00 to 3:00 (or 2:59:59) in both graphs?

I mean, in the first plot, for example, each individual value is plotted as marker followed by a line of half an hour. This is true for each value except the last one, which is plotted as marker but not followed by any line. I want to plot this last line so the plot will end at 3:00 because that is what my data means in reality.

Thank you.

Comment: I am having trouble understanding what you are looking for, do you want to plot data at 3:00 or just have the 3:00 tick at the end to show that the data ranges from 0:00 to 3:00?

Comment: @as11 In the first plot, for example, each individual value is ploted as marker followed by a line of half an hour. This is true for each value except the last one, which is ploted as marker but not followed by any line. I want to plot this last line so the plot will end at 3:00

Comment: Well I do not see any data for 3:00, so if you want it to end at 3:00, you must add additional data with shows the value that corresponds with the time 3:00

Comment: @as11 Ok maybe I don't have data at 3:00, but I have data until 2:59:59.99999 as I explained, so I want the plot to draw a line until almost 3:00. However, the plot ends at 2:30 in the first graph and at 2:00 in the second which is misleading. I think maybe a workaround is to add an additional point at 3:00 to complete the plot as you said. But I am asking for an easy way to do so.

Comment: I do not see any data for 2:59 in your data that you included.

Comment: @as11 I tried to explain it in the question. My data is in reality an average of a time period. For example, imagine an electric consumption meter registering data every half an hour. It would have measured 1 kWh in the time period from 0:00 to 0:30 and stored it with the timestamp at the beggining of the period (0:00) and so on. The last measure is at 2:30, meaning this is the consumption between 2:30 and 3:00 (or more exactly, 2:59:59.99). So in my particular case, I am interested in a plot which starts at 0:00 and ends at almost 3:00. However, visually talking, my plot ends at 2:30 or 2:00.

Comment: The problem is that you need to explicitly specify where you want your data to be plotted. It makes sense what you are trying to explain, but it is also needed to know that it will only connect to 3:00 automatically if you had a value past that i.e 3:30. That is why i suggested adding a value to that goes to 2:59 or 3:00 so that it knows to connect it till there. It wont automatically interpret that you want it to extend to 3:00

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By changing your Data to this:

```
csv = [
['2019-05-01 00:00', 6],
['2019-05-01 00:30', 8],
['2019-05-01 01:00', 7],
['2019-05-01 01:30', 3],
['2019-05-01 02:00', 8],
['2019-05-01 02:30', 4],
['2019-05-01 03:00', 4]]
```

I was able to get a graph like[image]